# div tag not collapsing/expanding using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the below html and the div containing class `tabHeader` is not expanding/collapsing at all.

```
<div class="tabHeader">
     <li><a href="#" id='onejltab' class="tablinks">1JL(Mobile)</a></li>
      <div class="insideTabHeader">
          <li><a href="/onejl/1" class="tablinks" style="text-align:center">Network</a></li>
          <li><a href="/onejl/2" class="tablinks" style="text-align:center">Application</a></li>
          <li><a href="/onejl/3" class="tablinks" style="text-align:center">Integration</a></li>
          <li><a href="/onejl/4" class="tablinks" style="text-align:center">Infrastructure</a></li>
      </div>
</div>
```

Have written the below `jquery` to collapse/expand the div `tabHeader`

```
$("#tabHeader").click(function () {

    $tabHeader = $(this);
    $insideTabHeader = $tabHeader.next();
    $insideTabHeader.slideToggle(500, function () {
    });

});
```

I'm not sure why the above jquery isn't working. Any help/solution would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Use the anchor id or class instead of the div

2- use `$tabHeader.closest('li').next();` instead of `$tabHeader.next();`

```
$("#onejltab").click(function () {

    $tabHeader = $(this);
    $insideTabHeader = $tabHeader.closest('li').next();
    $insideTabHeader.slideToggle(500, function () {
    });

});
```

***Demo***

```js
$("#onejltab").click(function () { 
    $tabHeader = $(this);
    $insideTabHeader = $tabHeader.closest('li').next();
    $insideTabHeader.slideToggle(500, function () {
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabHeader">
     <li><a href="#" id='onejltab' class="tablinks">1JL(Mobile)</a></li>
      <div class="insideTabHeader">
          <li><a href="/onejl/1" class="tablinks" style="text-align:center">Network</a></li>
          <li><a href="/onejl/2" class="tablinks" style="text-align:center">Application</a></li>
          <li><a href="/onejl/3" class="tablinks" style="text-align:center">Integration</a></li>
          <li><a href="/onejl/4" class="tablinks" style="text-align:center">Infrastructure</a></li>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yours is working fine in fiddle but not on my app. I'm checking on this. Will let you know. Thanks

Comment: @harshavmb be sure to includ the jquery .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: yeah, jquery is included. not sure why it isn't working. Thanks for your help. Will update you. I too wish you a great day... :)

Comment: got the issue, it was an issue with `$(document).ready(function() {});`. Have changed it now. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Hi, one more question, sorry for troubling. I want the tabs to be closed by default. Now, all the child tabs are expanded by default. Any chance the tabs can be closed by default? On click, it should expand. Thanks again.

Comment: @harshavmb in css add a class `.insideTabHeader{display : none;}` or if you have it just add `display : none;` to it .. if you need it with js you can use `$('.insideTabHeader').hide(0)`